# $_POST is not working while sending Chtml data from view to controller. Its showing an empty array

Tags: php, yii

I am new in Yii framework. I am using Chtml form to send data from view to controller and want to print the result and insert it to database. But in my case its showing an empty array. I couldn't able to understand where I am doing wrong. So please help me regarding this.

in controller

```
 public function actionTest1()  
    {
        $obj = new Pad;
        if(isset($_POST))
            print_r($_POST);// to check the desired result

        if(isset($_POST['Pad']))
        {
            $obj->attributes=$_POST['Pad'];
            if($obj->save()) // insert the data
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$obj->id));
        }

    }
```

in view

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('','post',array('id'=>'step1Form')); ?>
  <div class="stopPad">
      <div class="floatLeft padTop5 marRight5">
        <?php
    echo CHtml::radioButton('stoppad',false,array('value'=>'Stop Pad after goal is reached'));
    ?>
      </div>
      <div class="currencyText padTop4 floatLeft">Stop Pad after goal is reached</div>
      <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stopPad">
      <div class="floatLeft padTop5 marRight5">
     <?php
    echo CHtml::radioButton('stoppad',false,array('value'=>'No limites'));
    ?>

      </div>
      <div class="currencyText padTop4 floatLeft">No limites</div>
      <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    </div>

        <div class="nextText">
    <?php echo CHtml::link('Next >',array('pad/test1'));?>
      </div>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are not submitting your form and of course `$_POST` will be empty. Line below is just a link:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Next >',array('pad/test1'));?>
```

You must change it to :

```
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Next >');?>
```

And also add an action to your form.

Comment: I tried. But its still showing the same. Empty array.As per your suggestion I also added action in the form.

<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('pad/test1','post'); ?>

Comment: @geeta I think there is something wrong you are doing as I have tested your code and after submitting it had values. This is undeniable that if you click on submit button, `$_POST` will have values. As a suggestion, use yii's dumper instead of `print_r`: `CVarDumper::dump($_POST)`

Comment: And change `<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('pad/test1','post'); ?>` to `<?php echo CHtml::beginForm($this->createUrl('pad/test1'),'post'); ?>`

Comment: again the same thing. As I am new so I really don't have idea what actually I am doing wrong. If you have tested and had values so I will request you to paste the code here so that I can get to know what wrong is there in my code.It would be a great help.

Comment: Update your question with new code please, so I cane help you

Comment: I did. Please have a look and help me. @Ali

Answer (score 0):

Updating the question with the changes I have done. Its redirect me to pad/test1 showing array() as result.

in controller

```
public function actionTest1()  
    {

         $obj = new Pad;
        if(isset($_POST))
            CVarDumper::dump($_POST);// to check the desired result

        if(isset($_POST['Pad']))
        {
            $obj->attributes=$_POST['Pad'];
            if($obj->save()) // insert the data
                echo "=====";
        }

    }
```

in view

```
 <?php echo CHtml::beginForm( '','post'); ?>
  <div class="stopPad">
      <div class="floatLeft padTop5 marRight5">
        <?php
    echo CHtml::radioButton('stoppad',false,array('value'=>'Stop Pad after goal is reached'));
    ?>
      </div>
      <div class="currencyText padTop4 floatLeft">Stop Pad after goal is reached</div>
      <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="stopPad">
      <div class="floatLeft padTop5 marRight5">
     <?php
    echo CHtml::radioButton('stoppad',false,array('value'=>'No limites'));
    ?>

      </div>
      <div class="currencyText padTop4 floatLeft">No limites</div>
      <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    </div>

        <div class="nextText">
   <?php echo CHtml::button('Next >', array('submit' => array('pad/test1'))); ?>
      </div>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

Comment: Please change `CHtml::button` to `CHtml::submit("Next>")`

Comment: And also change `<?php echo CHtml::beginForm( '','post'); ?>` to `<?php echo CHtml::beginForm($this->createUrl('pad/test1'),'post'); ?>` or leave it empty if you're on current action

Comment: I am really sorry to inform you that its the same result (empty aray)after changing it as per your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

A common source of confusion among new Yii users is how the 'safe' validator works, how it works with other validators, and why it's necessary in the first place. This article means to clear up this confusion, as well as explain the notion of Massive Assignment.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/

Comment: can you please explain me where I have done wrong. Its still confusing. @pentium

Comment: @Pentium10 this is not related to safe and unsafe attributes. Op is not even submitting his/her form. So $_POST will not have any value.